# Laravel Livewire Dynamic Input Field

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i want to create a dynamic input field in laravel livewire. Most of what I saw and tried were always 2 input fields, but I only have 1 input field that needs to be expanded again and again I have the following Code:

**Livewire Class**

```
public $currentStep = 1;
    public $worker_number, $material, $consumed = 0,$supplier,$checked, $production_number;
    public $inputs = [];
    public $i = 1;
    public $updateMode = false;
    public $successMessage = '';
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function render()
    {

        $worker_number = session('worker_number');

        $data = array(
            'suppliers'=>$this->getSuppliers(),
            'materials'=>$this->getMaterial(),
        );

        if($worker_number != ""){
            $this->worker_number = $worker_number;
            if($this->currentStep < 2){
                $this->currentStep = 2;
            }
            return view('livewire.sheetswizard',$data);
        }else{
            return view('livewire.sheetswizard',$data);
        }

    }

    public function getSuppliers(){
        $suppliers = DB::table('supplier_x_material as sm')
            ->select('s.*')
            ->join('suppliers as s','sm.supplier', '=', 's.id')
            ->where('sm.material','=',1)
            ->get();
            
        return $suppliers;
    }

    public function getMaterial(){
        $material = DB::table('sheets as m')
            ->select('m.*','s.name as supplier')
            ->join('suppliers as s','m.supplier', '=', 's.id')
            ->get();
            
        return $material;
    }


    public function firstStepSubmit()
    {
        $validatedData = $this->validate([
            'worker_number' => 'required',
        ]);
        
        $this->saveDatatoSession();
 
        $this->currentStep = 2;

    }

    public function saveDatatoSession(){
        session(['worker_number' => $this->worker_number]);
    }
  
    public function secondStepSubmit($material)
    {
        $this->material = $material;

        $this->currentStep = 3;
        
    }

    public function thirdStepSubmit()
    {
        $validatedDate = $this->validate([
            'production_number.0' => 'required',
        ],
        [
            'production_number.0.required' => 'PA-Nummer ist erforderlich',
        ]
        );
        $this->currentStep = 4;
    }

    public function add($i)
    {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $this->i = $i;
        array_push($this->inputs ,$i);
    }

    public function remove($i)
    {
        unset($this->inputs[$i]);
    }
```

**My Blade File**

```
<div class="row setup-content" style="display: {{ $currentStep != 3 ? 'none' : '' }}" id="step-3">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h5> Produktionsauftrag</h5>
                <div class="form-group mt-3 mb-3 text-center">
                    <label class="mb-3" for="title">Bitte gib die Produktionsauftrag-Nummer (PA) ein:</label>
                    <div>
                                    <form>
                                        <div class=" add-input">
                                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-5">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="PA-Nummer" wire:model="production_number.0">
                                                        @error('production_number.0') <span class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                                    <button wire:click.prevent="add({{$i}})" class="btn btn-success mb-2">+</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        @foreach($inputs as $key => $value)
                                            <div class=" add-input">
                                                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <input type="text" class="form-control name_list w-150 mb-2" placeholder="PA-Nummer (Optional)" wire:model="production_number.{{ $value }}">
                                                            @error('production_number.'.$value) <span class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-danger" wire:click.prevent="remove({{$key}})">-</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="pb-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary nextBtn pull-right me-2" type="button" wire:click="back(2)">Zurück</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn pull-right" type="button" wire:click="thirdStepSubmit">Weiter</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Problem is that the extra Input Field has always the same key and also the same value. If I output the array, all inputs have the same integer value.Unfortunately, I don't really know what the problem is and would like to get your help

Comment: https://dev.to/jringeisen/how-to-create-dynamic-input-fields-with-laravel-livewire-14kn

Comment: Yes, I was on the site but the submit function isn't particularly helpful